# my vim jump to next word is quite slow, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc file, I have the following mappings:

```
nnoremap \ *
nnoremap \| #
```

for the jump-to-next-word and jump-to-last-word commands.

For some reason my jump-to-next-word command is slow, on the order of 1 second before it seems like the command is executed, while the jump-to-last-word shortcut is fine (no noticeable delay).  I've tried mapping different keys to the command, and it is only in some cases that there is this delay.

Does anyone know the cause of this behavior?

Comment: is the backslash your mapleader?

Answer (score 5):

Because `vim` is waiting for more key after you typing `\`

You can change the waiting time(default `1` second) by:

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=100 ttimeoutlen=100
```

(time out on mapping after `0.1` second, time out on key codes after `0.1` second).

Comment: @user1266594 I'd recommend not to use the `\` character for that, as it is used by many plugins. Changing the timeout will make those plugins less comfortable to use.

Comment: Nice! I also needed to set timeoutlen=1000 to not interfere with my various keybindings: jj <Esc>, etc. Those keybindings would not work with timeoutlen=100.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but not related to the mapleader. It turned out that there were some other commands that used my "jump to next word" key as a prefix (in my case that was `y`). Here is what I did:

1. Issue `:nmap` command to pull the list of all the mappings.
2. Mark the ones that start with your "jump to next word" key. In my case these were `yo` and `yO`.
3. Unmap this commands in your `.vimrc`. In my case these were `unmap yo` and `unmap yO`.
4. Reload your `.vimrc` with `:so $MYVIMRC` for changes to take effect.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of frustration in neovim

Answer (score 0):

If you intended to map backslash with first command I would suggest to put something like

```
let mapleader='_'
let maplocalleader='_'
```

into your vimrc (replace underscore with any sequence of symbols you are comfortable with) because many plugins create mappings whose `{lhs}` starts with `<Leader>` and thus vim is awaiting for next key in order to determine whether it was some of the plugin mappings as @kev correctly pointed out. If you put the above lines into the vimrc those plugins that use `*map <Leader>...` will now create mappings that start with underscore instead of starting them with backslash. If this does not help, check out `verbose map \` and read documentation of the plugins in order to determine whether there is an official way to make them generate mapping with another leader.